# Understanding particles relating the orbits of the state space and the representations of the Poincaré group on it

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

My teacher said the following:

> A particle is a set of states $\{ \vert\Psi\rangle \}$ that transform among themselves under Poincaré transformations.
>   Hence, a particle is a unitary irreducible representation of the Poincaré group.

I understand why it makes sense to talk of particles as in the first sentence. But I don't see how the second sentence follows. Let me try to be mathematically clear:

With the first sentence, we seem to be saying that a particle is an orbit of an element $\vert \Psi \rangle$ of the state space $\mathcal{E}$ (where the Poincaré group $G$ acts)
$$
      O(\vert\Psi\rangle)=\{ g\vert\Psi\rangle:g\in G \}
$$
With the second statement, we're saying that a particle is (the image of an) irreducible unitary representation $\Pi:G\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$ of $G$.

So I went on looking for a mathematical theorem of representation theorem that said something like "there is a bijection between the sets of all orbits of a set and the set of the images of the irreducible unitary representations of a group that acts on it". I couldn't find it.

Is there such a theorem? Am I interpreting this correctly? Although I am interested in understanding these topics deeply one day, right now I don't have the time, so I just want to see the idea behind this statement about particles.

Comment: The highlighted sentence is incredibly sloppy. The best mathematical translation I can imagine is "A quantum-mechanical particle is described by an irreducible unitary representation $\pi: G\to U(H)$ (where $H$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and $G$ is the Poincare group). Such representations can be derived from $G$-actions on some manifolds, e.g. orbits of such actions.  One way to do this is via the Orbit Method,  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_method."